# By modifying my DNS records, how can I have "test.mydomain.com" resolve to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080?

Tags: dns

First, this is a programming question because I'm trying to set up a test/QA server running alongside a production server.

Second, yes I should post this on Serverfault, but I tried logging in with THREE different OpenID providers, and every time I get an error saying this this provider isn't supported in the Beta (even though the icon is right there). To post a question you must log in.

Whew, okay.

Currently I have one **A** record with *@* host pointing to my server IP, let's say *111.11.11.11*. I then have a **CNAME** record with *www* host pointing to *@* from my **A** record.

The problem is that I have a different web server running on *111.11.11.11:8080*. I'd like to make another **CNAME** so that *test* host points to something like *@:8080*

To summarize:

*www.mydomain.com* should resolve to *111.11.11.11*

*test.mydomain.com* should resolve to *111.11.11.11:8080*

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com and team@serverfault.com

Comment: ... but it's available to everyone just by emailing OpenIDs to team@serverfault.com

Comment: I didn't know that - it's not on the serverfault.com page.

Comment: I think it's kinda lame to down-vote a legit question simply because it would be better placed on an alternate Beta site. Quite simply this could help other programmers trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Note that you don't even need to email your openid if you have >100 rep on stackoverflow

Comment: Voted back up.  This is a legit question.

Comment: @bdonlan - I ended up getting into Serverfault by e-mailing my OpenID url to team@serverfault.com as Mehrdad (and the error I got) said. After some time I was able to log in, though I couldn't use my default OpenID provider (Google) after reading one of the latest blog posts (switched to ClaimID for both sites). Overall I'd say this is a non-trivial switch for casual users, so I stand by my suggestion that until Serverfault becomes more accessable, we should relax a bit.

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote. I just voted to close.

Comment: Jeff says we will be able to move questions from one site to the other.  I expect this will get moved eventually.

Comment: @gbarry - That will be perfect. The DNS tag alone has 174 instances, so I'm sure we'll be moving over a lot.

Comment: So, should this be moved to ServerFault now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DNS A (address) record doesn't have port number. So, not, **that** is not possible.

What's possible is to have another IP for the same machine (e.g. 111.11.11.12) and let test.mydomain.com resolve to it. Then your first server should listen on the first IP only, and second on the second only.

P.S. There are DNS SRV records that allow to specify the port, but browsers DO NOT use them, alas.

Answer (score 3):

DNS only resolves to an IP address. However, if you have DNS resolve to an IP where Apache is located then you can use mod_proxy to proxy the request to an application server on port 8080. See this link.

http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/UsingModproxyWithJBoss

Answer (score 1):

No, DNS A records only resolves host names to ip address, it doesn't know anything about port numbers.

But you can always configure your webserver to serve differents pages depending on the host header (thus, making innesesary the use of port 8080). I could give you details but i would need to know the webserver you're using.

**EDIT:** If you're using tomcat you should add another Host directive, the details can be found here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/host.html

Comment: Tomcat 6 is the servlet container

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can't define a port inside your dns configuration.
It's not its purpose.
It's just about ip -> host and reverse.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. DNS controlls which IP the *domain* points to, it has nothing to do with the port. You can probably setup firewall rules to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dyndns.org [webhop](https://www.dyndns.com/services/webredirect/) service for just that exact situation.
It's free for up to 5 hosts.

Answer (score 0):

As boris said it's not possible.

But you can with certain services like SIP.

This involves using an SRV record on your dns.
But I'm afraid normal web browsers will ignore that.

More at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

But you could add another IP to your server. This way you could bind your servers to different IP addresses on the same machine. DNS would point to different IPs of course.

And it's a nice solution especially if you are using ipv6. Providers often allocates a whole bunch of ipv6 addresses like /64, so you can bind a different server on every one of them. :)

Answer (score -1):

It's possible using an Apache virtual host.  I don't know the exact syntax, but I know that is how rails works.  It is something like:

```
 <virtualhost *:8080>
 servername subdomain.domain.com
 serveralias subdomain.domain.com
 DocumentRoot /path/to/public
 </virtualhost>
```

restart apache.